# How to achieve OOP and organize code which is dependent on context in Android

Tags: android

Let's say I have a Payment SDK that uses Builder pattern to initialize it and it takes the context as a parameter to do so.

In order to support multiple payment SDKs, I want to create a PaymentMethod interface with methods such as init(), startPayment(), and cancelPayment() and it should also have some callbacks to specify successfully and failed transactions. Let's say we do that we Higher-order function.

Let's say I want to use PaymentMethod A I will implement the interface and implement all of its functions. For method B I would repeat the process.

I am doing this because when I want to change the Payment method I won't have to change the code in the activity. But In order to achieve this, I have to pass a **context** to the class implementing PaymentMethod Interface.

I know that passing a context is not a good idea and can lead to memory leaks.

My question is how to achieve this without a memory leak.

If there is a way, can someone post official references of the Android developer website for this as well?

Comment: Read about dagger

Comment: I know about dagger though, do you know any other way to do it? Passing a context to other util class in order to reduce the code in activity. One case would be where have an old project where adding dagger at this point is not an option.

Comment: Then pass context as argument to your util class and methods